# Why is script not detecting the word "star"?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have written a Python script to check passwords but this script is not able to detect word `"star"`.

My script is the following:

```
import os
import sys
import time

while True:
    user_password = input("Enter your password: ")

    # Processing String.
    try:
        user_password = int(str(user_password))
        inta = True
    except Exception:
        user_password = str(user_password).lower()
        inta = False
    passlen = len(str(user_password))
    if inta == True:
        print("PIN not supported.")
    elif passlen != 3:
        print(f"Password less than or greater than 4 characters not supported.")
    else: break


dic = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j','k',
        'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't','u','v',
        'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']

os.system('cls')
os.system('color 02')
if not inta:
    guess = ""
    a, b, c, d= 0,0,0,0
    st = time.time()
    while (True):
        guess = ""

        g1 = dic[a]
        g2 = dic[b]
        g3 = dic[c]
        g4 = dic[d]
        guess = f'{g1}{g2}{g3}{g4}'
        # print(guess)
        sys.stdout.write(f'\rPassword Guessing: {guess}, Time: {time.time()-st:.2f}s')
        sys.stdout.flush()

        if (guess!=user_password):
            if d==25:
            if c==25:
                if b==25:
                    a+=1
                    b,c,d=0,0,0
                else:
                    b+=1
                    c=0
            else:
                c+=1
                d=0
        else:
            d+=1
    elif guess == 'star':
        print('star')
    else:
        et = time.time() - st
        break

sys.stdout.write(f"\rYour password is {guess}, Time Taken: {et:.2f}s")
time.sleep(2)
os.system('color 07')
```

After running several times many other words like `"aaaa"`, `"rrrr"`, `"tttt"` are detected. But this script is not able to detect the word `"star"`.

Comment: your whole code makes absolutely 0 sense. starting with the fact you scan for a 4 letter passcode although your input requires the password length to be 3?

Comment: Following your indentions you have a `while` block with an `elif guess == 'start'`. There are no `elif`s for `while`s. You should use a [proper IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment), there are a lot more syntax errors which can easily be found by an IDE.

Comment: I am new to stack overflow so while typing in the code I made mistakes. Sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import os
import sys
import time
import string

while True:
    user_password = input("Enter your password: ")

    try:
        user_password = int(str(user_password))
        inta = True
    except Exception:
        user_password = str(user_password).lower()
        inta = False
    passlen = len(str(user_password))
    if inta == True:
         print("PIN not supported.")
    elif passlen != 4:
         print(f"Password less than or greater than 4 characters not supported.")
    else: break


dic = string.ascii_letters

os.system('cls')
os.system('color 02')
if not inta:
    cracked = False
    st = time.time()
    for g1 in dic:
        for g2 in dic:
            for g3 in dic:
                for g4 in dic:
                    if (g1+g2+g3+g4==user_password):
                        et = time.time() - st
                        cracked = True
                        print(f"\rYour password is {g1+g2+g3+g4}, Time Taken: {et:.2f}s")
                        break
                if cracked:
                    break
            if cracked:
                break
        if cracked:
            break
```

Not the nicest but it does what you want

```
Enter your password: star
Your password is star, Time Taken: 0.59s
```

Comment: Thank You! From your answer I got the defect in my code. Just I manage my variables and now my working fine.